# Display value of header instead of *** in NestJS Swagger UI

Tags: nestjs, swagger-ui

I have added the new header `x-zp-auth-provider` to Swagger UI by `addSecurity` and I want it to display its value instead of *****

Is there any way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not out of the box.

You'll have to fork [Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/), modify the relevant code, rebuild the assets with your changes, and then configure NestJS to use your forked version instead of the standard Swagger UI.

The code that masks API keys and Bearer tokens with `******` is here:
[api-key-auth.jsx](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/src/core/components/auth/api-key-auth.jsx)
[http-auth.jsx](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/src/core/plugins/oas3/components/http-auth.jsx)